# Symfony, Invalid data (AppBundle\Entity\InterventionType), expected "AppBundle\Entity\Intervention

Tags: api, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to insert a line to my base, from postman to a local api with some foreign keys and I have this bug :

> "message": "Invalid data \"1\"(AppBundle\Entity\InterventionType),
>   expected \"AppBundle\Entity\Intervention\"."

It pointed to the bad Entity and I don't know why. I'm targeting "Intervention", and doctrine seems to go in InterventionType...
Here's my entity :

```js
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * InterventionRapport
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="intervention_rapport", options={"comment":"Table répertoriant les retours associés aux différentes interventions (commerciales et techniques) - Egalement utilisée pour rémunérer les techniciens et calculer les frais kilométriques tech/com"})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class InterventionRapport
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Intervention")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="intervention", nullable=false)
     */
    private $intervention;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $message;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="statut", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $statut = '0';

    /**
     * some other things
     **/

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    
}
```

and the entity targeted with foreign key:

```js
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Intervention
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="intervention")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Intervention
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\InterventionType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * Some other things
    **/

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

And finally my json:

```
{
    "message": "Steuh plait !",
    "statut": 1,
    "datemaintenanceprevue": "2017-08-23T15:00:00+00:00",
    "heuresintervention": 1,
    "heurestrajet": 0.5,
    "kmtrajet": 27,
    "deleted": 0,
    "intervention": 1,
    "id": 2
}
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add code of the controller

Comment: Perhaps: @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\InterventionType")

Comment: @Cerad, Ineeded to have that relation, but I solved the problem with a friend.
I've changed my Conntroller and editied the way I create the object so it's OK

Answer (score 0):

I found a slution by changing the way I created the line. I don't put the intervention id directly, I pass it into the url :

```js
class RapportController extends Controller
{  
    /**
     * @Rest\Post(
     *    path = "/reports/intervention={id}",
     *    name = "app_report_create"
     * )
     * @Rest\View(StatusCode = 201)
     * @ParamConverter("report", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request, InterventionRapport $report)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $intervention = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Intervention')
            ->find($request->get('id'));

        //$report = new \DateTime($datemaintenanceprevue);

        $report->setIntervention($intervention);

        $em->persist($report);
        $em->flush();

        return $report;
    }
```

So, I don't need to post the intervention id from my client' json :

```
{
"message": "Steuh plait !",
"statut": 1,
"datemaintenanceprevue": "2017-08-23T15:00:00+00:00",
"heuresintervention": 1,
"heurestrajet": 0.5,
"kmtrajet": 27,
"deleted": 0,
"id": 2
```

}

I don't know if it's the correct way to do it, but it solved the problem. Hope it can help someone else.